# Multipage forms for joomla (looking outside the box)

Tags: forms, webforms, joomla

I have created a number of forms using various Joomla components which have more or less worked successfully.

Recently I have attempted to create mult-page forms - the forms work...but they are slow as molasses. Having spent a couple of weeks trying to resolve this and not seeing any signs of improvement ......

I wonder if anyone has experience of using hosted forms services in Joomla either using a wrapper or as a static page within a Joomla site.

Any pointers or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way but need much time is to create it into external PHP files - like form1.php >> form2.php >> ... >> form_last_and_post_data_to_email.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried RSForm? I use it on my site, and multi page forms are supported